# ServiceStack Renaming SyncReply Client

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, servicestack

I am looking at using a ServiceStack web service in place of an existing third-party web service.  I have matched the DTOs used by the third-party service.  However, the client is expecting a proxy class named "NotificationServiceClient", like this:

```
var client = new NotificationService.NotificationServiceClient();
var response = client.SendNotification(message);
```

I am unable to alter the source code for the client application, so I would like to configure ServiceStack to use NotificationService for the client proxy, instead of SyncReply.  Is there a way to do this?

**UPDATE** - It seems what I'm looking for is a way to configure ServiceStack so that it generates a different value for the name attribute of the wsdl:service tag; from SyncReply to NotificationServiceClient.  I can save the current WSDL, manually manipulate it, and verify the proxy class name using a throw-away client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment by mythz, I have overridden the GenerateWsdl in my AppHost, and set the ServiceName property on the wsdlTemplate.  Here's an example:

```
public override string GenerateWsdl(WsdlTemplateBase wsdlTemplate)
{
    wsdlTemplate.ServiceName = "NotificationService";
    return base.GenerateWsdl(wsdlTemplate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use [ServiceStack's .NET Service Clients](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client) for consuming 3rd Party APIs, they're only designed and opinionated towards consuming ServiceStack Services.

The only HTTP Client we recommend for calling 3rd Party APIs is [HTTP Utils](http://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils) which is a our general purpose HTML client.

Comment: I don't have control over the actual client in production, so I'm looking for a way to control the name in the WSDL.

Comment: @Jason If you just want to modify the WSDL returned by ServiceStack you can override [GenerateWsdl() in your AppHost](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/574a82d58a3099d3b819659008b42b7dccc67bb3/src/ServiceStack/ServiceStackHost.cs#L935) which will let you modify the WSDL XML returned by ServiceStack.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I was looking for!  I'll submit a complete answer based on this suggestion.  Thanks.